# Appending a pattern to a preexisting regex

Tags: awk

I have this regex that allows a space followed by visible characters

```
[[:space:]][[:graph:]]+$
```

How can I construct the possibilities of having either some pattern `ptrn` or the same pattern `ptrn` followed by the additional one above?

Comment: This is better suited for https://www.stackoverflow.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk uses POSIX *extended regular expressions*, so you can use `?` as a quantifier to represent either zero or one occurrence of the preceding pattern:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'ptrn' 'foo bar' 'ptrn bar' | awk '/ptrn([[:space:]][[:graph:]]+)?$/'
ptrn
ptrn bar
```

In GNU awk aka `gawk` you can also use a `{n,m}` quantifier:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'ptrn' 'foo bar' 'ptrn bar' | gawk '/ptrn([[:space:]][[:graph:]]+){0,1}$/'
ptrn
ptrn bar
```